# best way for add scope reference in function

Tags: javascript, performance, scope, closures

hi guy what the best way for add scope obj reference to a function.

my example , i have a super object.

```
var SuperObj = new PIXI.sprite();

SuperObj.action = new subObj();

SuperObj.action.actionFunction = function(){// need to acces to SuperObj};
```

when i add function stuf to action, i need add a scoped reference to his parent.

so i need have ascces to SuperObj in my function from subObj

so in my context its preferable to proceed like this ?

```
var motion = this._motions[motionName];
var action = (function(motion,actions){

    return function(){
        console.log('actions: ', actions); // by closures
    };
})(motion,this); // this scoped by closures in function
this.actions.add_newAction(action,motionName,actionName);
```

or like this

```
var motion = this._motions[motionName];
var action = (function(motion){

    return function(){
        console.log('actions: ', this.scoped ); // by scope obj
    };
})(motion); action.scoped = this;
this.actions.add_newAction(action,motionName,actionName);
```

what its the most performance way, or maybe you have another suggest way ?
i need performance optimal and most functional way.
thank

Answer (score 0):

If it needs access to the super obj, it should probably be in the super obj.

In the super class, you have access to the child as a property.

So, the method should be this instead:

```
SuperObj.addActionFunction = function(){// need to acces to SuperObj};
```

actions is a list (of the action class) based on what's above, not a direct property of superobj and if you need access to that list, another reason it should be in superobj.